# Как изменить вид ссылки

Tags: php, .htaccess

Написал модуль статей, который выводит на сайте категории статей, и сами статьи. 
Саму статью можно почитать по адресу: `site.ru/statiya1` где *1* это id статьи в базе, по этому id я делаю выборку из базы, данных о статье, её заголовок, сам текст и т.д.

А хочу сделать так, чтобы статьи можно было читать по ссылке `site.ru/v-mire-zhivotnix` , где *v-mire-zhivotnix* это заголовок статьи, только в транслите.

Думал решить через `.htaccess`.

Как возможно такое сделать не переписывая модуля? Или хотя-бы по минимуму чтоб.
И вообще, как реализовать подобное?
Буду благодарен за информацию. Я не прошу код, а саму идею реализации, ну и если можно примеры кодов не помешали бы.
Не какой CMS нет, все с нуля.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если через `.htaccess` действовать, то лучше сделать так.

1. Адрес статей оформить в подпапке - `site.ru/articles/v-mire-zhivotnix`. Это не обязательно, но это поможет структурировать сайт, да и `.htaccess`
2. В `.htaccess` написать что-то типа `RewriteRule ^articles\/(.+)$ articles.php?url=$1`
   Тогда адрес статьи будет в `$_GET["url"]`

Ну а если в подпапку вставлять не вариант, то чуть иначе.
`.htaccess` берет все, что после первого `/`, а код уже должен проверять статья это или нет.

Вот так

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

И не забудьте в таблице статей добавить поле url и сделать его уникальным индексом.
И кодом потом доставать новую статью типа `SELECT * FROM articles WHERE url='" . $_GET["url"] . "'`

Comment: Это то я знаю, меня интересует как открывать статью по такой ссылке, то есть нужно правило для .htaccess

Comment: тогда и в вопросе хотя бы УПОМЯНУТЬ htaccess надо бы :) и метку поставить.... - сейчас отвечу

Comment: Хорошо. Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Первый вариант, с подпапкой, я так понимаю для этого нужно то что ответили впервый раз? Если так то отлично, это то что нужно! Так это?

Comment: нет, не совсем... под подпапкой я имел просто адрес статьи. все равно `.htaccess` нужен, просто он сразу будет отправлять в скрипт `articles.php`, который 100% уверен, что данный `url` - это именно статья, а не что иное на сайте. это просто для облегчения структуры сайта. Ну а уже `articles.php` работае так, как я писал в первый раз - ищет статью по `url` в базе данных

Comment: Простите. Не могли бы вы написать еще раз то, что писали в ответе впервый раз.

Comment: @user193064 - добавил абзац в ответ